# How to select mutiple rows at a time in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I have a DataFrame object and an unknown number of rows, I want to select 5 rows each time.

For instance, `df` has 11 rows , it will be selected 3 times, 5+5+1, and if the rows is 4, only one time will be selected.

How can I write the code using `pandas`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with a little arithmetic. This should be clean.

```
chunks = [g for _, g in df.groupby(df.index // 5)]
```

Depending on how you want your output structured, you may change `g` to `g.values.tolist()` (if you want a list instead).

Answer (score 1):

#### `numpy.split`

```
np.split(df, np.arange(5, len(df), 5))
```

#### Demo

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(11)))

print(*np.split(df, np.arange(5, len(df), 5)), sep='\n\n')

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

   A
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9

     A
10  10
```

Comment: Nice, you could also add `array_split`, as well.

Comment: Neat!  Reading about `array_split` now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop and then use the index for indexing the DataFrame:

```
for i in range(len(df), 5):
    data = df.iloc[i*5:(i+1)*5]
```